# How to dynamically load external library with Webpack and Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I would like to use Tweakpane library for rendering GUI (https://github.com/cocopon/tweakpane). I want to use it only during app tuning on my side - load it dynamically when its functionality is required and I don't want to distribute it to users. First, I imported it like this in the top of the file:

```
import { Pane } from "tweakpane";
```

It worked well, but whole Tweakpane library was added into bundle by Webpack bloating the final build.
Later I found, that I can mark the library as external in webpack.config.js like this:

```
    externals: {
        tweakpane: "Tweakpane"
    },
```

and add script tag into index.html like this:

```
<script src="tools/tweakpane.js"></script>
```

Up until now, it works - tweakpane.js is separated from my app bundled with Webpack and in code I can use it with all benefits given by typings.

Next, I wanted to remove script tag from index.html and load the script dynamically inside my code when it is needed like this:

```
        let scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

        scriptTag.onload = function () {
            console.log(`tweakpane loaded`);
        };
        scriptTag.onerror = function () {
            console.error("Couldn't load tweakpane library script. Make sure tweakpane.js is in tools folder.");
        }
        scriptTag.src = "tools/tweakpane.js";
```

The loading works, because I can see the script loaded, but inside my app, when I want to instantiate new tweakpane Pane (`this._pane = new Pane();`) I get this error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Pane')".

I can workaround it with this: `this._pane = new window["Tweakpane"].Pane();` - asking window for Tweakpane. It works, but I loose all benefits from type definitions as window["Tweakpane"] is of type 'any'.

It kind of makes sense to me - when tweakpane script is on page from beginning, then my app bundle can do some setup and it works. If I load it later, than it means, that this setup failed and when I load the script dynamically, there is something missing.
But I have no idea, how to fix it?

I also tried dynamic import with `await import("tools/tweakpane.js");` and made it work. But in this case whole tweakpane library was bundled along with my app (ignoring external setting in Webpack). I tried also all Webpack comment hints, but with no success.

So, I would be happy if there is way how to:

- keep tweakpane separate in its own library file (tweakpane.js),
- load it only when its functionality is requested for the first time,
- use it inside app, that is bundled with Webpack,
- enjoy all the benefits from type definitions.